# Python string comparison failing

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, comparison

small Python prog' to sort downloads folder by matching the extension,
I am getting a False (it seems to me) string match in the following.
I searched but seemed to only find issues regarding REGEX matching, or more complex stuff!

seperate the extension

```
for filename in os.listdir(src_base_folder):
orig_title, orig_ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
```

make lower case for ease of matching and strip the leading "."
I suspect my issue is here somehow..

```
extension = str.lower(orig_ext)[1:]
```

The test below is working fine for everything except "S22F350FH.icm",
a colorscheme file for setting up a monitor.

I print out the "extension" which shows as "icm" yet **I am getting a FALSE match**
in this code against the extensions for various image types:

```
if extension == "jpg" or "jpeg" or "png" or "gif" or "bmp":
```

Appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: There's no `icm` in this line `if extension == "jpg" or "jpeg" or "png" or "gif" or "bmp"`.

Comment: @MayankPorwal "icm" is the extension of the filename, it is inside the variable "extension", this was done in the "splitext(filename)" code.

Comment: @Dee Got it. Please check my answer. Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `if extension == "jpg" or "jpeg" or "png" or "gif" or "bmp"`, you should use:

```
if extension in ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "bmp"]:
```

Answer (score 1):

The interpreter treats conditionals as follows:

```
if expr_1 or expr_2 or expr_3:
```

More concisely,

```
if (expr_1) or (expr_2) or (expr_3)
```

Evaluating your program, the interpreter treats `if extension == "jpg" or "jpeg" or "png" or "gif" or "bmp"` as:

```
if (extension == "jpg") or ("jpeg") or ("png") or ("gif") or ("bmp"):
```

Since non-empty strings are truthy, this will always evaluate to `True`. Instead, use what @Mayank suggested, `if extension in ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "bmp"]:`.

Comment: Ok, that's interesting, 'truthy', but also interesting that I have several other lines for matching other file types (PDF[pdf], Docs[xlsx,docx,odt,ods], ZIPS[zip, gz, tar]) and yet only this file *slips* through. O_O

Comment: @Dee try `bool("jpg")` and `bool("")`. Non-empty strings, when cast to a boolean, are `True`. This leads to the terminology *truthy*.

Comment: thanks, I get it now; so my *if extension == "jpg"* is a poor choice of comparison for string(s).
Mayank's answer is definitely working and much more concise as well. So a win win. I will rework my other code to try and remove the "truthy" comparisons - lucky I guess that they worked thus far? =)